# "The first lesson" vs "The first lessons"

Tags: grammatical-number

How to correct?

I would like to say:

> It's the first English **lessons**.

But my teacher says it should be:

> It's the first English **lesson**.

Comment: Your teacher is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your teacher is correct.

The words "It is the first" implies there is only one – the very first one. "It" is a singular pronoun; coupled with the definite article, it's pretty clear we are only talking about one English lesson. Therefore, we should use the singular.

We could alter the wording slightly, though, and the sentence could use the plural. Let's say we're not talking only about Lesson 1, but Lessons 1 through 4, out of 50 lessons total. In that case, we could say:

> Those are the first English lessons.

but notice how, in talking about more than one lesson, the sentence has shifted from the singular to the plural. That is why "*It is..."* has been changed to *"Those are..."*

Comment: Or you might say, "This is the first **of the** English lessons."

Comment: @Jim - Excellent point. The preposition changes the structure of the sentence entirely, where the first part can be in the singular, and the prepositional phrase can reference the plural. Or that can be reversed, too: _"Those are the last in the line."_